# how to monitor email sending progress with a progressMonitor

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-mail, swingworker, progressmonitor

I'm developing a risk management system and part of the functionality is sending emails to every member who is allocated a corrective action to attend to. So as a measure to keep the user updated while the emails are being send i have decided to use a progress monitor and swing worker as the GUI freezes during the email sending process. Im not really sure of how to achieve this but what i do know is that i will need to create a task that handles the email sending , a property changelister to monitor the email sending process and an actiondlister to initiate the email sending. Below are the classes and method i have written but i do not know how to put them together to achieve my set goal.

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(NewJFrame.this, "Sending an email", " ", 0, 100);
    progressMonitor.setProgress(0);
    task = new Task();
    task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    task.execute();

}
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())){
        int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
        progressMonitor.setProgress(progress);
        String message = String.format("Sending message ..%d%%...\n", progress );
        jTextArea1.append(message);
        //progressMonitor.setNote(task.getMessage());
        if(progressMonitor.isCanceled() || task.isDone()){
            progressMonitor.close();
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            if(progressMonitor.isCanceled()){
                task.cancel(true);
            }else{
            jTextArea1.append("Message Send");
            }
        }
    }
}
class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        int progress = 0;
        setProgress(0);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            progress += 5;
            progress++;
            setProgress(progress);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.test.biz");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                 return new PasswordAuthentication("herbert@conceptium.biz", "Kaylad1*#");
                        }
                  });
            try {
                Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("herbert@conceptium.biz"));
                msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("herbertd@test.com,herbert@test.biz"));
                msg.setSubject("This is a test");
                msg.setText("This is a test a message");
                Transport.send(msg);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(NewJFrame.this, "Email succesfull sent...!" );
            }
            catch(MessagingException | HeadlessException e){
                //progressMonitor.isCanceled();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(NewJFrame.this, e.getMessage() +". "+ "Please check your internet connection");
                  }
            }catch(InterruptedException | HeadlessException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(NewJFrame.this, e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
    }
@Override
public void done(){
    setCursor(null);
    //jTextArea1.append("Done!\n");
    progressMonitor.setProgress(100);
}
```

}

I have hardcoded the email address but its suppose to dome from the base. For simplicity purposes i have removed that method and only put enough code to put across my point. some help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would pass the `SwingWorker` all recipients who need to be addressed and send the email as a single unit of work, perhaps using BCC if you don't want everyone to know who's received the emails, as to if you can monitor the physical transportation of the mail, I'm not sure you can

Comment: There's no really god way to monitor the network I/O involved in sending the message.  A complicated solution would be to create your own Socket class that wraps the standard Socket class and adds the ability to monitor the socket I/O on the socket input/output streams.